# 24 hours of values

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a sql table : date (Y-m-d) / time (00:00:00) / power (INT)

When I select a date from an inline datepicker, I am trying to post 3 HighCharts graph (one-24 hours, two-31 days of month, three-12 months of year) and I need to get the values out of the table for the chart to be created.

For the day, I need the 24 values for each hour '100,200,300,200,300 etc..'

Here is the PHP for the "day" but it is not working...

```
<?php
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) 
          ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) 
          : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  
$sql = "SELECT HOUR(time), COUNT(power) 
FROM feed 
WHERE time = DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
GROUP BY HOUR(time) 
ORDER BY HOUR(time)"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
echo $row['choice'].'<br />'; 
?>
```

This has been confirmed by another individual that the code does not work, would anyone have a helpful solution to fix the error ?

Alan

Comment: Explain in details what does not work.

Comment: I do not get the values I am asking for... The script above is intended to get values of 1 day (1 value for each of the 24 hours in a single day) 23, 23, 21, 12, 15, etc... I need these values for a "day" graph I am planning on my website. I am also planing a graph for a month (values by day, and a graph for the year (values by month). The code does not produce the values, and I am asking for assistance to correct a mistake that must be in the wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all your help !

The problem was in the first string, I only had to change the date format in addition to your wonderful examles !

```
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("m",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("m");
```

Thank You Very Much !

Alan

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, your `SELECT` gives you only the results which happened *exactly* 24 hours before the current moment. What you need is a range. Example for 1 hour (indentation added for clarity):

```
WHERE `time` BETWEEN 
   DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
   AND DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 23 HOUR)
```

This way, you'll get results with `time` in the 1-hour range of "now - 24 hours" and "now - 23 hours". The [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator is equivalent to this:

```
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
   AND `time` <= DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 23 HOUR)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much ! I can understand that... I would use the same method for selecting the days of a month, and months of the year, but I would use "date" and "month" in the place of "time"

Comment: As for taesing all my scripts with this, is it best to go directly to it with the url method - www.site.com/folder/dayPower.php?choice=2010-12-03

Comment: From your question, I assumed `time` is the name of a column storing the relevant date and time. And yes, this works for any interval.

Comment: Time only stores the time... the column Date stores the date. and then the last column is the Power with the Power This is the way the Solar Panel inverter device sends out the data from the data port, so I must follow that format.

Comment: I am a bit confused about the INTERVAL for a month, some have 28, 29, 30 or 31 days...

Comment: @hkalan2007: Actually, that's an interesting question. I think it gives you the date with month 1 less - at least that's my interpretation of the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: When I go test this using the BETWEEN operator, I only get a single value... I thought this will give me 24 values (1 for each hour)..Why would that be ?

Comment: Maybe you only have a single data point between the two times? Try to test with absolute datetimes - e.g. `BETWEEN '2010-12-02 11:45' AND '2010-12-02 12:45'`. Do you still get a single data point?

Comment: Before, the value was 65, when I use the time BETWEEN 11:00:00 and 12:00:00 I get a value of 64. Hmmm

Comment: This only gives me a single value... $sql = "SELECT HOUR(time), COUNT(power) AS choice 
FROM feed 
WHERE `time` BETWEEN  
   DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  
   AND DATE_SUB('".$choice."', INTERVAL 23 HOUR) 
GROUP BY HOUR(time) 
ORDER BY HOUR(time)";

Comment: Hmm, I see you're grouping by hour. Extend the `BETWEEN` to be for the whole day, and you should be getting 24 rows (something like "between choice-24 hours and choice" should do it)

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to walk over the rows:

```
$sql = "
SELECT HOUR(time) as h, power
FROM feed 
WHERE date = '".$choice."' 
ORDER BY HOUR(time)"; 

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['h'].":".$row['power']'<br />'; 
}
```

This will give you the power per day for a given month:

```
$sql = "
SELECT DAY(date) as d, SUM(power) as powerday
FROM feed 
WHERE MONTH(date) = '".$month."' 
GROUP BY DAY(date) 
ORDER BY DAY(date)"; 

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['d'].":".$row['powerday']'<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Yes I can... Now I have to do the same for MONTH and YEAR

Comment: Just change `hour(time)` by `month(date)` or `year(date)` and also modify the where and order by clauses accordingly.

Comment: I always get 24 values, there are 24 fot month (should be 31 for this month) and I get 24 values for the year (only 12 months in a year)... Mysql date and time are my bigest headache I never seem to get right.

Comment: The 'WHERE date = $choice' needs to stay the same, as that is the date that comes from the datepicker on the html page to the php file we are dealing with here (seen in the string at the top of the php here). I am only getting the single value of 1 day (today) with this...  hmmm

Comment: Hello, I fixed it. The problem was in the post string. I had to change the date format there for the sql to get the right dates.... Thanks for your help ! Alan